# Blown ignition coil after battery hooked up incorrectly

Tags: honda, civic, vtec

2004 Honda Civic EX w/ VTEC

I had a buddy of mine go have my battery tested, also had him put it back in my car. The only problem is he put the cables on the wrong way Which ended up blowing my main battery fuse but I don't know how he didn't catch his mistake....

Anyway tried to start the car and didn't gave up on it went about his business and left the battery plugged in the wrong way until the following afternoon. Corrected the cables, replaced the fuse.

So now the following, I'm driving to work and the 3rd ignition coil blows up on me. Got the car towed home, went to the auto parts store, got a new one and the car turned on engine sounds good problem solved I thought. Five minutes later see one melts this time my plug is broken.

Does this have anything to do with the battery being plugged in wrong way?

Comment: Probably coincidence - are the plugs due for a change? When were they last serviced? And a bunch of formatting would not go amiss...